# X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25,random_state=1)

Tags: python, function, split

What is purpose of this line :

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25,random_state=1)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This line splits your data in two datasets: one for training your model and the other to test the "performance" of your model on data never seen before (75% for training data and 0.25% for testing data, the random state is to reproduce the same split each time you run your program).

Answer (score 0):

For neural networks you have input features (`X`) and output labels (`Y`). It's very important to split your data into a training dataset and testing dataset.

To make this easy sklearn has a function called
`train_test_split(*arrays, test_size=None, train_size=None, random_state=None, shuffle=True, stratify=None)`.

Here's the [documentation for `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)

---

Going through the function we can see that:

1.) `X` is your input features array

2.) `Y` is your output label array

3.) `test_size = 0.25` states that you want your testing data to be 25% of your overall data. Therefore your training data will be 75% of your overall data.

4.) `random_state = 1` Controls the shuffling applied to the data before applying the split.

5.) Your question is why do you have 4 outputs (`X_train`, `X_test`, `y_train`, `y_test`). It is because `X` will be split into `X_train` (75%) and `X_test` (25%) and then `Y` will be split into `y_train` (75%) and `y_test` (25%). It's all put onto one line.